# Embedded surface in simply connected manifold is two sided?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Suppose M is embedded surface(compact without boundary) in N^3 which is a simply connected three dimensional manifold, then why does M have to be two sided? Is there any example for this? I found a paper named "orientability of hypersurface in $R^n$", but I  don't quite understand the short argument. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I don't see "properly" in the question. But if you can explain with properness and why it matters, that would be better. Sorry, I think probably these surface are closed.

Comment: Is $N$ orientable?

Comment: Not sure, does it matter?

Comment: Every simply connected manifold is orientable. Thus, $M$ is two sided if and only if it is orientable.

Comment: I agree with Eduardo Longa.

Comment: You need $N$ simply connected, not just orientable. Consider $\Bbb RP^2\subset\Bbb RP^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, $RP^2$ is a one-sided (non orientable) closed surface in $RP^3$ which is orientable but not simply connected. This is a good counterexample, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard kind of argument that you can find in textbooks on differential topology. It works in any dimension, so $N$ can be an $n$-manifold and $M \subset N$ can be a compact submanifold of dimension $n-1$. I think probably Guilleman and Pollack have this argument. Here's a sketch.

Assume $M$ is one sided. It follows that $M$ has a one-sided component. By replacing $M$ with that component, we can assume that $M$ is connected.

Pick an arc $\alpha$ that hits $M$ transversely in a single point. Since $M$ is connected and one-sided, there exists an arc $\beta \subset N$ that is disjoint from $M$ and that stays in a regular neighborhood of $M$ and such that $\alpha \cap \beta = \partial \alpha = \partial \beta$. It follows that $\gamma = \alpha \cup \beta$ is a circle in $M$ that intersects $M$ transversely in exactly one point. By perturbing $\gamma$, we can assume it is smooth.

Suppose now that $N$ were simply connected. Then there would be a smooth function $f : D^2 \to N$ such that the restriction $f : S^1 = \partial D^2 \to N$ is a homeomorphism onto $\gamma$. By using general position arguments, after perturbing $f$ one may assume that in addition the map $f$ is transverse to $M$. It follows that $f^{-1}(M)$ is compact 1-manifold properly embedded in $D^2$, and so the set of endpoints of this 1-manifold forms an even number of points in $S^1$. From this it follows that the cardinality of the finite set $\gamma \cap M$ is even. But it's not, it's $1$.

Comment: Lee, this actually is not in Guillemin and Pollack, but the tools are all there. Indeed, the result they call the Boundary Theorem  says that if $f$ extends to the disk, then the mod-2 intersection number of $f$ with a closed submanifold of complementary dimension must be $0$, precisely as you indicate.

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand the argument now. It is actually same argument as the one in the paper "Orientability of hypersurface in $R^n$" except that i's in Euclidean space.

Comment: I think that the OP is referring to the paper of Hans Samelson "Orientability of hypersurfaces in R^n." Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 22 (1969), 301–302.  Samelson says that the argument generalizes to simply connected manifolds.