# Non orientable normal bundle gives a non simply connected manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, orientation

Let $X$ be a compact connected manifold and $M\subset X$ be a compact connected hypersurface. If the normal bundle $NM$ is not orientable, then $\pi_1(X)\not= 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161117/embedded-surface-in-simply-connected-manifold-is-two-sided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal bundle of an hypersurface is a $\mathbb{R}$-bundle which is flat and defined by a representation $\pi_1(M)\rightarrow GL(\mathbb{R})$ if $\pi_1(M)=1$, the normal bundle is trivivial henceforth oriented.

Another way to see this is to take a  good trivialisation $U_i$ $(U_i\cap U_j$ is connected) of the normal bundle and consider the chech cocycle $sign(g_{ij})$ where $g_{ij}$ are the coordinate change. It defines a flat bundle which is trivial if and only if the normal bundle is oriented.

Comment: But the question is about $\pi_1(X)$, not $\pi_1(M)$....