# Simply-connected 3-dimensional manifold cannot contain a projective plane

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I think I can obtain the following statement:

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ A simply-connected 3-dimensional manifold cannot contain a projective plane.

Using the following proposition:

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ A simply-connected 3-dimensional manifold is homotopy equivalent to $S^{3}$

this excludes the existance of a 2-sided projective plane via an orientability argument but I'm not sure about to deal about a 1-sided $P^{2}$. Moreover I feel like this argument might be overkill and I can probably show it in a more neat and simple way, any hint?

Comment: Ok, apparently If I'm understading this correctly I could not deal with one sided because I can not have a one sided surface in a simply connected manifold via this argument: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161117/embedded-surface-in-simply-connected-manifold-is-two-sided

Comment: Do you know Alexander duality?  If so, you can prove:  If $M$ is a connected closed manifold with $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, and $N\subseteq M$ has codimension $1$, then $M\setminus N$ has two components.  Then one can trivialize the normal bundle of $N$ in $M$ by looking at normal vectors which points into one componenet of $M\setminus N$.  It then follows that the tangent bundle of $N$, $TN$, is stably isomorphic to $TM$, so both bundles are orientable or both are non-orientable.

Comment: But the hypothesis $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ implies $M$ is orientable:  if $M$ is non-orientable, the orientation covering corresponds to some subgroup $K$ of index $2$ in $\pi_1(M)$.  The map $\pi_1(M)\rightarrow \pi_1(M)/K\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ factors through $H_1(M)$ and shows that $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial.  Universal coefficients now gives that $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial, giving a contradiction.

Comment: No never heard of it, thanks for the help anyway, appreciated.